# Laravel Passport not authenticating with JWT cookie (self consuming API)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I've gone through the entire page of documentation and as far as I can tell I have everything set up exactly as the documentation states. However, when I attempt to make a GET request to `/api/users` it **always** returns a `401 Unauthorized`.

If I inspect the request, I see that the `laravel_token` is indeed being passed along with the request, as well as CSRF.

At this point, I'm not really sure why it's always failing to authenticate, but it's pretty frustrating and I'm sure it's something minor that I'm overlooking somehow.

I'm using Laravel 5.7.5.

Configuration steps done:

- Ran `php artisan passport:install`
- Added trait to User model
- Added `Passport::routes()` to `AuthServiceProvider::boot()`
- Changed API driver to passport in `config/auth.php`
- Added `CreateFreshApiToken::class` to web middleware

Comment: How do you inspect the request? Did you try it by browser? if so, you are doing in a wrong way. You should use some applications to make json call to your endpoints. something like postman. Something that is able to set application/type in header. If you are calling endpoint by correct header, then check your files key files permissions.

Comment: @train_fox I'm inspecting the request that's made with Axios, which is how the documentation for Passport does it. That's definitely not the wrong way of doing so. I'm not sure what you're trying to mean by `files key files permissions`.

Comment: when you run `php artisan passport install` laravel will make 2 files, private and public key. Check storage directory to find them and check their permissions, required permission is 644.

Comment: @train_fox Ah, yeah, those files have correct permissions.

Comment: Do you trying to access the default route defined in api.php route file?

Comment: @train_fox Yep, I actually found the problem, but don't have a good solution for it. In `TokenGuard::decodeJwtToken`'s call to `encrypter->decrypt`, if I change `Passport::$unserializesCookies` to false, it works. But this introduces a vulnerability to XSS attacks, so I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You should ensure that the EncryptCookies middleware is listed prior to the  CreateFreshApiToken middleware in your middleware stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186017/discussion-between-nathan-and-train-fox).

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of digging, I finally figured out what my issue was.

In version 5.6 and later of Laravel, cookies are no longer serialized/unserialized. However, Passport still expects that the cookies are serialized. Neither the documentation for Laravel or Passport point this out, and hopefully they'll get more in sync so this isn't an issue.

To fix this, you just need to add `Passport::withoutCookieSerialization();` to `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::boot()`